# What is viewersPercentage in YouTube Analytics API report - Demographic data

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, analytics

Referring to [Youtube Analytics API (Channel reports) Viewers demographic data](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports#demographic-playlist-reports)

What is the base metric for calculated ["viewersPercentage"](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/metrics#viewerPercentage)?

Is it a sum of daily views on all channel videos or is it a sum of all-time views for this channel?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You choose the base by specifying the [report parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/data_model#choosing-report-parameters) `startDate` and `endDate`.

So if the `startDate` and `endDate` are the same, it will be the sum of daily views, otherwise it will be the sum of views of the date span.